# How to evaluate $\int_0^\pi \cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) \cos(4x)\, dx$

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

Is there an easy way to evaluate the integral $\int_0^\pi \cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) \cos(4x)\, dx$?

I know that I can plugin the $e$-function and use the linearity of the integral. However this would lead to 16 summands which I really dont want to calculate separately.

Comment: Use http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html

Comment: The easiest way to approach integrals like this is with Euler's formulas for the trig functions.

Comment: plugging in $exp(ix)=:z$ is indeed a good idea - it seems you get many terms, but only those with $z^0$ contribute, and that comes only from $z^0=z^4z^1z^{-3}z^{-2}$ and $z^0=z^{-4}z^{-1}z^{3}z^{2}$

Comment: @Moo, Plane Trigonometry : Sidney Luxton Loney  OR A treatise on plane trigonometry : Hobson, Ernest ..

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Because I like it, I will add a tricky approach ($C$ denotes the unit circle):

$$
I=\frac{1}{2}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx\prod_{n=1}^4\cos(nx)\underbrace{=}_{z=e^{ix}}\frac{1}{32i}\oint_C\frac{1}{z^{11}}\prod_{n=1}^4(z^{2n}+1).
$$

Now, since $\oint_Cz^{n}=0$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n\neq-1$, only the terms of the product with total power of $10$ will contribute. There are exactly two of them $2+8=4+6=10$, so

> $$
> I=\frac{1}{32i}\oint_C\frac{2}{z}=\frac{\pi}8
> $$

where the last equality results from the residue theorem.

---

Fiddling around with generalizations of this result and consulting OEIS I stumbled over this interesting set of slides: http://www.dorinandrica.ro/files/presentation-INTEGERS-2013.pdf
So integrals of this kind have a deep connection to problems in number theory which is pretty awesome

Comment: What a beautiful solution (+1)!

Comment: Thank you very much, this is the kind of answer i was hoping for

Comment: you are mssing a minus sign,  $\oint_Cz^{n}=0$ for $n\in \mathbb{Z}$ and $n\neq -1$

Comment: those anonymus downvoters seem to have a misarable life...

Comment: I like upvoting downoted answers, nice idea.

Comment: No one expected this solution and the linked PDF out of this simple integral!!! +1

Answer (score 12):

**HINT:** We have the following identities

$\cos(A+ B) = \cos A \cos B - \sin A \sin B$ and

$\cos(A-B) = \cos A \cos B + \sin A \sin B$

$2\cos A \cos B = \cos(A+B) + \cos (A-B)$

$\cos A \cos B = \dfrac{\cos(A+B) + \cos(A-B)}{2}$

Take $\cos x$ and $\cos 4x$ together and $\cos 2x$ and $\cos 3x$ together.

Then $\cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) \cos(4x) =\\ \frac18[1 + \cos(10x) + \cos(8x)+ \cos(6x)+2\cos(4x)+2\cos(2x)+\cos(x) ]$.

Now you can do with your usual integration formula.

Comment: nice $\,(+1)\,$

Comment: shouldnt i get quadratic terms if i do this?

Answer (score 2):

Using [Werner's](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/WernerFormulas.html) formula with $a\ge b>0$ so that $a\pm b$ are integers

$$\int_0^\pi\cos ax\cos bx\ dx=\dfrac12\int_0^\pi\{\cos(a+b)x+\cos(a-b)x\} dx=\cdots=\begin{cases}0&\mbox{if } a\ne b\\ 
\dfrac\pi2 & \mbox{if } a=b\end{cases}$$

Now, $(2\cos x\cos4x)(2\cos2x\cos3x)=(\cos3x+\cos5x)(\cos x+\cos5x)$

$=\cos3x\cos x+\cos x\cos5x+\cos3x\cos5x+\cos5x\cdot\cos5x$

So, $\displaystyle4\int_0^\pi\cos x\cos2x\cos3x\cos4x\ dx=\dfrac\pi2$ for $a=b=5$

Comment: is the formula an indefinite integral?

Comment: @Manjoy, No, for the definite one

Comment: then the limits can be any arbitrary numbers but the integral would be $\dfrac{\pi}{2}$?

Comment: @Manjoy, please find the updated version

Comment: I was looking for an integration and thus came to know about this formula. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967191/integration-of-cosx-cos2x-cosnx-dx here is my problem described. need your favour. thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

There is a [well-known](https://qualifications.pearson.com/content/dam/pdf/A%20Level/Mathematics/2013/Specification%20and%20sample%20assessments/N38210A-GCE-Mathematical-Formulae-Statistical-Tables.pdf) identity which says

$$\cos A + \cos B = 2\cos\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)$$

If we put $\frac{A-B}{2} = x$ and $\frac{A+B}{2}=2x$ then we get $A=3x$ and $B=x$, so $$ \cos x \cos 2x \equiv \frac{1}{2}(\cos x+\cos 3x) $$

We can repeat this for $\cos 3x$ and $\cos 4x$. Solving $\frac{A-B}{2} = 3x$ and $\frac{A+B}{2}=4x$ gives $$\cos 3x \cos 4x \equiv \frac{1}{2}(\cos x + \cos 7x)$$
Putting this together gives
$$\cos x \cos 2x \cos 3x \cos 4x \equiv \frac{1}{4}(\cos x+\cos 3x)(\cos x+\cos 7x)$$

Now, you need to expand these brackets and follow the same procedure to simplify $\cos x \cos x$, $\cos x \cos 7x$, $\cos 3x \cos x$ and $\cos 3x \cos 7x$.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$$I=\int_0^\pi \cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) \cos(4x)\, dx,$$
since $\cos(x+\pi) \cos(2x+2\pi) \cos(3x+3\pi) \cos(4x+4\pi)=\cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) \cos(4x)$,
$$I=\int_{-\frac\pi2}^\frac\pi2 \cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) \cos(4x)\, dx
=2\int_0^\frac\pi2 \cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) \cos(4x)\, dx.$$
Make change $x\to\frac\pi2-x$, we get
$$I=2\int_0^\frac\pi2 \sin(x) \cos(2x) \sin(3x) \cos(4x)\, dx.$$
So
$$2I=2\int_0^\frac\pi2[\cos(x) \cos(2x) \cos(3x) \cos(4x)+\sin(x) \cos(2x) \sin(3x) \cos(4x)]\, dx$$
$$=2\int_0^\frac\pi2\cos^2(2x)\cos(4x)\, dx
=\int_0^\frac\pi2[1+\cos(4x)]\cos(4x)\, dx$$
$$=\int_0^\frac\pi2\cos^2(4x)\, dx
=\int_0^\frac\pi2\frac{1+\cos(8x)}{2}\, dx
=\frac{\pi}{4}.$$
Hence
$$I=\frac\pi8.$$